# How can I play metal Slug or The King of Fighters(KOF) 2002 in ubuntu

Tags: games

I use ubuntu 12.04. I want to play Metal Slug and KOF 2002 in my ubuntu. What should I do to install those games in my pc?

Please show in detail; I have never played such games in pc.

Comment: What kind of games are these?  Are they PC games?  Android games?  Game system games?  Can you provide links to their websites?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "Metal Slug" you're referring to one or more of the side-scrollers, they should work fine with Wine ...at least if it's version 1.0. See [this Wine AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11432). Here are [the details](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20002). The testing is pretty old but since it worked very well then, the same software will most likely work well in Wine in Ubuntu now. Test it and see!

I haven't found information in the AppDB for KOF 2002 or King of Fighters 2002. But you may want to search yourself, in case I'm missing something. Especically if you know another name for the software. Anyway, you can try it and see.

Assuming you have the Windows versions of these games, just [install Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) (see also [this documentation](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)), then run the installers like you would on Windows. If you can't run them by double-clicking on them, then right-click on them and click Wine Windows Program Loader. (If you don't see that, then you might need to click Open With and fine Wine or Wine Windows Program Loader.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAME instruction :

Add the main repository for unofficial builds:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c.falco/mame
```

(optionally) add the repository for "u"(nstable) builds:

(Skip this step to stick with main, stable, not-"u" releases!)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c.falco/umame
```

Now update the information on your box:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install the package from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install mame
```